# Can't access Fedora server remotely

Tags: linux, fedora

For about 2 weeks now, I have not been able to connect to any services (httpd, mysql, ssh, etc..) on my server remotely.  I can access everything from inside the local network just fine.

I thought maybe the ISP started blocking some ports so I set up a XAMPP install on a different local machine.  I redirected httpd and sql ports to that machine and was able to access them from outside the network just fine. This leads me to believe it is an issue with the server.

I'm a little confused though as I was able to access the server remotely just fine up until about 2 weeks ago.

The server is running Fedora Core 15.

If I need to post some diagnostic output or anything let me know and I'll add it to the post.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT: UPDATE:**

It turns out I am unable to see the internet from the server as well.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 p8p1
0.0.0.0         10.1.10.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p8p1
```

Comment: can you ping the server by its hostname from remote network? what does "nmap -sS hostname" comes up with? oh okay so no connection to WAN from the server?

Comment: I can ping the server remotely.  nmap shows ths host as down, but run with -Pn shows it as up with all ports being filtered

Comment: Can you stop iptables daemon just for test?

Comment: Brought iptables down, still have same results

Comment: is that host in AWS or rackspace or whatever cloud?

Comment: Nah, it's running on a linux box inside our network

Comment: Ok, so how do you get to that machine from outside before? Did you have to do port forwarding on the company firewall?

Comment: Yeah, I have all the relevant ports forwarded to the server.

Comment: Can you see them? http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ It looks like your port forwarding stopped working.

Comment: I can't see the ports when they are forwarded to the server, but when I forward them to another machine running apache/mysql I can see them

Comment: Oh, I missed your update that you do not have connection outside from the server. You need to fix that apparently.

Comment: Good to see another face from MN. :) I'm just a bit south of you in Shoreview.

Comment: Can you ping the gateway? Is that getaway correct? What is your network connection?

Comment: Yeah I can ping the gateway just fine

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the server has the correct IP address set as its default gateway. Also verify its subnet mask.

Comment: Looks like the ip and mask is set correctly

Comment: All the symptoms you describe intricate a routing problem. You checked the default gateway, correct? That value is key for this server to be able to communicate outside its subnet.

Comment: I updated the post with the output of route -n